# Add type during Import-Module

Tags: vb.net, powershell, powershell-module

Is there anyway in PowerShell to `Add-Type` when importing a module?

I have a custom VB DLL that I'm importing as a module. The DLL has 2 imports in it:

```vbnet
Imports Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ManagementProvider
Imports Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ManagementProvider.WqlQueryEngine
```

The function that relies on the `WqlQueryEngine` doesn't work until I do:

```psh
Add-Type "C:\Program Files (x86)\Configuration Manager\Console\bin\AdminUI.WqlQueryEngine.dll"
```

Is there anyway to do this during the import? Or change where PowerShell is looking for an assembly?

Also why do I have to do this?
The files the import is relying on are both in the same directory? 
The first import relies on `C:\Program Files (x86)\Configuration Manager\Console\bin\Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ManagementProvider.dll`.

Why does one work and the other needs to be added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a module manifest (.psd1) file for your module (and you should), you can specify a list of required assemblies (`RequiredAssemblies = @()`). This will cause PowerShell to load them before your own module loads the VB DLL.

Module manifests are described [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878337(v=vs.85).aspx) in detail.

As for why one works and the other doesn't: It's hard do say. Assemblies already in the GAC don't need to be specifically loaded, maybe that's the case?

Answer (score 1):

Your powershell module should have a [manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878337%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that lists the dependencies.

The important lines from the linked page are:

```
# Assemblies that must be loaded prior to importing this module
# RequiredAssemblies = @()
```